# Java FX 8: TextArea LineHeight is smaller than actual when got from FontMetrics

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8

I have a small sample JavaFX 8 app and want to implement TextArea scrolling to an exact line number.
Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.Font;

import com.sun.javafx.tk.FontMetrics;
import com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit;

import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.*;

public class App extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setWidth(600);
        primaryStage.setHeight(400);

        TextArea area = new TextArea();

        int lineCount = 20;

        String text = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {
            text += "LINE" + (i + 1) + "\n";
        }
        area.setText(text);
        area.setEditable(false);
        area.setFont(javafx.scene.text.Font.font(Font.MONOSPACED));

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        vbox.setSpacing(8);

        vbox.getChildren().add(area);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        FontMetrics metrics = Toolkit.getToolkit().getFontLoader().getFontMetrics(area.getFont());
        Text t = (Text) area.lookup(".text");

        double lineHeight = metrics.getLineHeight();
        double actualLineHeight = t.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight() / lineCount;

        System.out.println("LineHeight: " + lineHeight);
        System.out.println("ActualHeight: " + actualLineHeight);
        System.out.println("Diff: " + (actualLineHeight - lineHeight));

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(metrics);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("LayoutX "+t.getLayoutX());
        System.out.println("LayoutY "+t.getLayoutY());
        System.out.println("Width: "+t.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth());
        System.out.println("Height: "+t.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight());

    }
}
```

This is its' output regarding heights:

```
LineHeight: 15.1328125
ActualHeight: 16.8
Diff: 1.6671875000000007
```

This is the full FontMetrics and dimensions:

```
FontMetrics: [maxAscent=12.066895, ascent=12.066895, xheight=7.109375, baseline=0, descent=3.065918, maxDescent=3.065918, leading=0.0, lineHeight=15.1328125, font=Font[name=Monospaced Regular, family=Monospaced, style=Regular, size=13.0]]

LayoutX 8.0
LayoutY 4.0
Width: 314.0
Height: 336.0
```

When I use the actual height, scrolling is very precise.
Sure, I can use this workaround to make it work, but I wonder if I have missed to count something else when using the LineHeight.

Just to know, maybe anyone knows?

Comment: Why did you add the `javafx-8` tag, instead of the `javafx-2` tag? Please clarify the version that you're using. It could be a example created for javafx 2 that is used with javafx 8 or the tag could simply be wrong.

Comment: Sorry for that. I am really confused with their versions. I have this in THE javafx.properties:

    javafx.runtime.version=8.0.66
    javafx.runtime.build=b17